# How to create fail2ban filter for phpmyadmin attacks

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I am trying to figure out how to create a failregex filter for fail2ban to safeguard against the attacks below. I tried the following failregex expressions but they are not matching anything from the /var/log/https/error_log

```
failregex = ^\[[^\]]+\] \[error\] \[client <HOST>\].*File does not exist: .*pma* *\s*$
```

OR

```
failregex = ^[[^\]]+\] \[error\] \[client <HOST>\] File does not exist: *phpyadmin* *\s*$
```

Here are the probes that I am trying to create rules for

```
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:46 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpmyadmin2015
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:46 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpmyadmin2016
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:47 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/phpmyadmin2017
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:48 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/PMA2014
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:49 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/PMA2015
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:49 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/PMA2016
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:49 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/PMA2017
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:50 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/PMA2018
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:52 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/pma2015
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:52 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/pma2016
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:52 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/pma2017
[Sat Aug 05 15:42:53 2017] [error] [client 109.188.133.141] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/pma2018
```

The regex expressions are not correctly recognizing the format in which the logs are being created. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just need one wild card rule that scans for a) File does not exist and b) any of the following strings on that error line pma*, php*

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestions above, but after countless tries here are the expressions that worked.

```
[Definition]
ignoreregex = 
failregex = \[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)MyAdmin.*
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)mysqlmanager.*
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)PMA.*
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)pma.*   
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)php-my-admin.*  
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)myadmin.*   
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)administrator.*     
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)xmlrpc.*            
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)testproxy.* 
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)phpMyAdmin.*
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)db.*    
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist:.*(?i)sql.*
```

If someone has plesk on centos, they can use these rules to thwart attacks. My server kept having the apache process run at 100% cpu usage.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious error I can see is here -

```
pma* *\s*$
```

That's matching `pm`, following by `a` zero or more times.
Then after that it's matching a space zero or more times, followed by `\s` (space or tab) zero or more times.

So basically it has to end with `pma` followed by zero or more spaces.
Same with the other regex.

You should try something like `pma.*\s*` (assuming you need to account for possible spaces at the end of the line.

Edit - The full expression should be something like the following, although obviously I can't really test it.

```
\[client <HOST>\] File does not exist: .+pma
```

Comment: What would the whole failregex rule be

Comment: ^\[[^\]]+\] \[error\] \[client <HOST>\] File does not exist: .+pma.+$ is not matching anything after I do fail2ban-regex. Outputs Lines: 26778 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 26778 missed

Comment: According to https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8 fail2ban matches the timestamp itself, so the regex should exclude that. I've updated the answer although as I can't really test fail2ban myself it may require minor adjustments